# BSOD after RAM upgrade on Windows 10 pro 64 bit

Tags: bsod

I'm using Dell Latitude 5400 model and its come up with 8GB ram defautt. I'm a developer while additionally I'm adding 8G ram due to slow performance. after upgrading laptop whenever im working laptop and OS starting time its blue screen error like. kernel security error and your pc ran into problem. Just like that.

Comment: Have you tried removing the RAM again to see if the problem persists?

Comment: default ram it wont show, while adding additional ram, that time only its through error. the additional ram is similar configuration of default ram only. and we change another different rams in that laptop aslo. But its showing that only. different errors different time.

Comment: You should edit your question with the exact error.  Generally if it started after adding new hardware, then that would be the issue.